# How to reslove permission denied while building docker compose

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to build following docker file and then run it but I'm getting this error

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "./doc8": permission denied: unknown
```

My docker file is as follows in that trying to build two containers one go and another id PostgreSQL:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  postgre-db:
    container_name: postgre-db
    image: postgres:12.2-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  doc8server:
    container_name: doc8server
    image: {IMAGE_NAME}
    env_file:
      - doc8.env
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.doc8server.multistage
    ports:
      - "{PORT}:{PORT}"
    volumes:
      - doc8data:/opt/app/assets/pdfs
      - doc8data:/opt/app/assets/pdfs/originalFiles
    depends_on:
      - postgre-db
volumes:  
  pgdata: {}
  doc8data: {}
```

this my run command

```
docker compose up -d
```

And this my dockerfile

```
FROM golang:latest as builder

LABEL maintainer="Doc8 <example@gmail.com>"

WORKDIR /app/invos_server_golang

COPY go.mod go.sum ./

RUN go mod download

COPY . .

WORKDIR /app/invos_server_golang

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o doc8 .

FROM rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd:latest

WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY --from=builder /app/invos_server_golang/doc8 .
COPY --from=builder /app/invos_server_golang/doc8.env .

EXPOSE {PORT}

CMD ["./doc8"]
```

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong

Comment: share your dockerfile once please

Comment: Hi, @Harsh Manvar I am added my dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a permission issue when trying to execute the ./doc8 command within the container. You can modify the docker file to ensure the executable has the correct permissions before running it.

**MODIFY THIS IN THE DOCKERFILE:**

```
# Add execute permissions to the executable
RUN chmod +x ./doc8

CMD ["./doc8"]
```

Comment: (Assuming your Go code is in a `package main`, the `go build` command should make its output file executable already, and it might be helpful to understand why this `chmod +x` is needed.)

Comment: In a typical Go project with a main package, the go build command already produces an executable file that is executable by default. The **chmod +x** command in the Dockerfile is not usually necessary in this scenario. But in some cases, the build environment inside the Docker container may have different default file permissions compared to the local development environment. This can result in the executable file not being executable by default, hence requiring the **chmod +x** command.